# Como inferir o tipo ao implementar uma função abstrata

Tags: typescript

Tenho a implementação **formatter** da classe **UserFormatter** que extende o **AbstractFormatter**

Quero que o intellisense saiba que o **payload** é o tipo passado no genérico do **AbstractFormatter**, o mesmo para o retorno da função

Dessa forma que fiz o intellisense não reconhece
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E não quero ter que tipar explicitamente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
// abstração
abstract class AbstractFormatter<T, R> {
  protected abstract formatter(payload: T): R

  public format(payload: T | null | undefined): R | null {
    if (!this.hasPayloadData(payload)) {
      return null
    }

    return this.formatter(payload as T)
  }

  public formatList(payload: T[] | null | undefined): R[] {
    if (!this.hasPayloadData(payload)) {
      return []
    }

    return (payload as T[]).map(this.formatter)
  }

  private hasPayloadData<T>(payload: T | null | undefined): boolean {
    return payload !== null || payload !== undefined
  }
}

// extensão
interface UserModel {
  name: string
  lastName: string
}

interface UserResponse {
  fullName: string
}

class UserFormatter extends AbstractFormatter<UserModel, UserResponse> {
  // aqui quero que TS saiba que o payload é do tipo UserModel
  protected formatter(payload) { // e a response é do tipo UserResponse
    return {
      fullName: `${payload.name} ${payload.lastName}`
    }
  }
}

const userFormatter = new UserFormatter()
const user = userFormatter.format({ name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' })

console.log(user)
```

Comment: Em `AbstractFormatter<UserModel, UserResponse>` você define os tipos que a implementação do `formatter` vai receber. Como na class `UserFormatter` você está de fato fazendo a implementação do método, a tipagem `AbstractFormatter<UserModel, UserResponse>` vai obrigar você a seguir o tipo daquel método, afim de evitar que voce passe um `payload` com um tipo incompatível com `UserModel`, logo voce **deve explicitamente informar os tipos** afim de evitar erros no programa.

Comment: Tenha em mente que o explícito é melhor que o implícito, entao faça bom uso dos tipos em TS e não tenha preguiça de escrever código. Sempre deixe-os o mais claro possível.